# De-Anonymizing an Anonymous Function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably quite a simple problem, but it's causing me to scratch my head, so I'm posting it here.

I have some jQuery in the following form:

```
if (jQuery('.SearchRegions:checked').length == 0) { 

jQuery('.SearchRegions').each(function(){

        //code

    });

} else {

jQuery('.SearchRegions:checked').each(function(){

        //the same code     

    });

}
```

Obviously it seems ridiculous to repeat a big block of code inside each of these functions.  But when I tried to name and move the function, it all seemed to break down - perhaps because of issues with scope and/or jQuery(this) inside the function no longer referring to the same object?

Can anyone help me by posting a general idea of what my code should look like? (Or any other optimisings or recastings to make it work would be much appreciated!)

Comment: you can have the common function accept the `this` part as a parameter. I can expand this to an answer with example code if you'd like

Comment: On an unrelated note, your code currently scans the DOM three times.  You can improve its speed by "caching" your jQuery objects: `var $regions = $(".SearchRegions"), $checked = $regions.filter(":checked"); if (!$checked.length) { $regions.each(...); } else { $checked.each(...); }`

Comment: Both of those comments are good and useful points - I'm having some "aha, NOW I see" flashes of comprehension!

Comment: @Ben: Does "caching" a jQuery object like that entail any risks of losing track of the object's changing values?  e.g. if I create a variable called $input to cache 'jQuery('#input').  Would if($inputfield.val != 0) work later on?  Don't want to merrily assign all of my DOM elements to variables and then discover I've broken everything.  (In the code sample given, your suggestion seems without possible drawback, of course...)

Comment: — jQuery objects don't get "updated" when the DOM changes, meaning that if you have a reference to a node which gets removed, it will still point to the orphaned node.  Similarly, if you create a variable for `$li = $("li")` then add new paragraphs to the DOM, your original `$li` won't pick them up ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peUDf/)).  In general, however, they're perfectly safe.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely just define a function and use it by name:

```
function someHandler(event) {
  // code code code
}

jQuery('.SearchRegions').each(someHandler);
```

Note that when you refer to the function by name, you **don't** include "()".

Comment: Hmm, you're dead right of course.  I wonder where my initial difficulties were stemming from?  Probably something at least as silly as adding () at the end of the function call... Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that closures are indeed the problem, you can parameterize your "anonymous" function to pass those values in to it.  For example:

```
function eachRegion(values, $container, foo) {
    // common code which uses scope variables `values`, `$container`, and `foo`
}

// elsewhere, in code defining `values`, `$container`, and `foo`...

if (jQuery('.SearchRegions:checked').length == 0) { 
    jQuery('.SearchRegions').each(function(){
        eachRegion(values, $container, foo);
    });
} else {
    jQuery('.SearchRegions:checked').each(function(){
        eachRegion(values, $container, foo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Another good suggestion, and enlightening about how jQuery works, or can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your function as a variable and use that in your each method call.

```
var yourEachFunction = function(){$("ul").append("<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>");}

if (jQuery('.SearchRegions:checked').length == 0) {
    jQuery('.SearchRegions').each(yourEachFunction );
} else {
    jQuery('.SearchRegions:checked').each(yourEachFunction );
}
```

Example of this working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/ctHw5/).